# ssrs ratio from matrix columns

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have one matrix of data that looks like

```
       | Mar  | Apr | May
A      | 110  | 85  | 65
B      | 95   | 75  | 55
```

I would like to add another matrix that displays the month to month change of these as a %, so that the data is calculated as

```
       | Mar  | Apr          | May
A      | null | (85-110)/110 | (65-85)/85
B      | null | (75-95)/95   | (55-75)75
```

How can I do this?

Comment: If you had months as rows, it would be straightforward to use `LAG`.  Is there any chance you could work with the transpose instead?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to create the query for the ratio part as above in sql-server. Insert this into table or temporary table and select from there into the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

you should explain lil more about your requirement.how did you get that table.?

try something like,

```
 declare @t table(col varchar(200),Mar int ,Apr int,May int)
insert into @t values ('A',110,85,65),('B',95,75,55)
SELECT col
    ,NULL
    ,((apr - mar) / cast(mar AS DECIMAL(5, 2))) * 100
    ,(may - apr) / cast(apr AS DECIMAL(5, 2)) * 100
FROM @t
```